# How to get input data from django request.POST

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I want to get the input data from my frontend so I can create an object from my backend. This is my input request:

```
return axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/',{
   name: name,
   description: description,
   category: this.category
},
this.config
)
.then(res=>this.props.update(res.data))
.catch(err=>console.err(err));
```

where name, description, and category are my input args, and this.config is just the the token.

In my backend I am using a Viewset to handle all my requests. So far I have a one for GET but now I want one for POST. This is my code:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        user = request.user
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(user=user)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def create(self, request):
        data = request.POST["name"]
        print("name",name)
        return Response("test")
```

I tried all variations of trying to extract my info from request.POST
I tried `request.POST.get('name')`, `request.POST['name']`, and other stuff. They all return None/KeyError. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`request.data`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data)

```
name = request.data['name']
```

This case is only applicable if DRF/Django receives the data from your client.